# python pip upgrade - TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, pip, upgrade, typeerror

I tried to upgrade pip.

So I typed `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in cmd.

And this message appeared:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site.py", line 546, in main
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site.py", line 457, in venv
    os.path.join(exe_dir, conf_basename),
  File "C:\Python\lib\ntpath.py", line 106, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path.encode('utf-8')
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: have you tried any solution so far?.. and don't forget to mention which platform you are using.

Comment: Run CMD or PowerShell with admin privs.

Comment: I searched that error message, but there are not solutions about pip upgrade. And I use windows 10. Sorry:(

Comment: I just ran CMD with admins privs, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I solved my problem by just reinstalling python! Thank you all you guys :)